# What does {...props} in this React Component mean?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Just starting out with react-router.

I'm using [react-router@next](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/v4) (version 4) when I came across this bit of code in [github](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/1159) (at the bottom). I have weak React + ES6-fu thus require your help.

1. Does {...props} here refer to sending props to the component?
2. How does {...props} here impact custom="prop"?

z

```
<Match pattern="/foo" 
       render={(props) => ( 
         <YourRouteComponent {...props} custom="prop"/> 
       )} 
/>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

consider the below example:

```
props = {
    propA: "valueA",
    propB: "valueB",
    propC: "valueC"
};
```

then,

```
<SomeComponent {...props} />
```

is equivalent to

```
<SomeComponent propA="valueA" propB="valueB" propC="valueC" />
```

---

```
<SomeComponent {...props} propC="someOtherValue" />
```

equivalent to

```
<SomeComponent propA="valueA" propB="valueB" propC="someOtherValue" />
```

---

Also please note that

```
<SomeComponent propC="someOtherValue" {...props} />
```

will become

```
<SomeComponent propA="valueA" propB="valueB" propC="valueC" />
```

The **order** is important.

Read more on [JSX Spread Operator `...`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#spread-attributes)

Comment: in your last example, propC="someOtherValue" gets overwritten by propC on {...props} ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one other example in a more practical way.
Suppose you have developed a very basic (for simplicity for this post) reusable `<TextInput/>` Component & want to reuse it over the whole application.
The definition is like this.

```
function TextInput({htmlId, name, type="text", ...props}){
    return(
        <div>
            <input
                id={htmlId}
                name={name}
                type={type}
                {...props}
            />
        </div>
    )
}
```

And here you are implementing the above component like this.

```
class ExampleOptional extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <TextInput
                htmlId="name"
                name="firstName"
                text="text"

                /** Props(place="XYZ & state="ABC") below are defined and destructured in TextInput 
                 Definition because there is {...props} defined in TextInput 
                 definition, if there is no {...props} in definition, no other than id, name & type 
                 props will be handled  */

                place="XYZ"
                state="ABC"
            />
        )
    }
}
```

So if you give anything apart from **"htmlId, name & text"** to TextInput as a prop, it will be get handled by {...props} which you defined in the TextInput component definition.
Otherwise, it won't be there in the DOM of TextInput. (As you can see from the below picture, place & state props that were not defined in the original TextInput component definition gets handled automatically)

[image]

**NOTE:** Whether you have props destructured( {...props} ) or not, you will be able to find all your props passed in Chrome's Developer tools React's Component tab, but it does not have any impact on DOM or concerned element.

Answer (score -2):

If {...props} has "custom" attribute, then custom the last value is "prop"(rightmost value).

Comment: please explain your answer